# FFMPEG not enough data (x < y), trying to decode anyway

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, direct3d

I'm trying to make videos of Direct3D games using a C# app.  For non-Direct3D games I stream images from Graphics.CopyFromScreen which works.  When I copy the screen from Direct3D and stream it to FFMPEG I get:

> [bmp @ 00000276b0b9c280] not enough data (5070 < 129654), trying to
>   decode anyway

An MP4 file is created, but it is always 0 bytes.

To get screenshots from Direct3D, I am using [Justin Stenning's Direct3DHook](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook).  This produces images MUCH bigger than when I get images from Graphics.CopyFromScreen (8 MB vs 136 KB).  I've tried increasing the buffer (-bufsize) but the number on the left of the error is not impacted.

I've tried resizing the image to 1/6th the original.  That reduces the number on the right, but does not eliminate it.  Even when the number on the right is close to what I have for Graphics.CopyFromScreen I get an error.  Here is a sample of the current code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;
using Capture.Hook;
using Capture.Interface;
using Capture;
using System.IO;

namespace GameRecord
{
    public class Video
    {
        private const int VID_FRAME_FPS = 8;
        private const int SIZE_MODIFIER = 6;
        private const double FRAMES_PER_MS = VID_FRAME_FPS * 0.001;
        private const int SLEEP_INTERVAL = 2;
        private const int CONSTANT_RATE_FACTOR = 18; // Lower crf = Higher Quality https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264
        private Image image;
        private Capture captureScreen;
        private int processId = 0;
        private Process process;
        private CaptureProcess captureProcess;
        private Process launchingFFMPEG;
        private string arg;
        private int frame = 0;
        private Size? resize = null;


        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the Videos by gathering frames and processing via FFMPEG.
        /// </summary>
        public void RecordScreenTillGameEnd(string exe, OutputDirectory outputDirectory, CustomMessageBox alertBox, Thread workerThread)
        {
            AttachProcess(exe);
            RequestD3DScreenShot();
            while (image == null) ;
            Logger.log.Info("Launching FFMPEG ....");
            resize = new Size(image.Width / SIZE_MODIFIER, image.Height / SIZE_MODIFIER);
            // H.264 can let us do 8 FPS in high res . . . but must be licensed for commercial use.
            arg = "-f image2pipe -framerate " + VID_FRAME_FPS + " -i pipe:.bmp -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf " +
                CONSTANT_RATE_FACTOR + " -preset ultrafast -s " + resize.Value.Width + "x" +
                resize.Value.Height + " -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 30000k -y \"" +
                outputDirectory.pathToVideo + "\"";

            launchingFFMPEG = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "ffmpeg",
                    Arguments = arg,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                }
            };
            launchingFFMPEG.Start();

            Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //creates and start the instance of Stopwatch

            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            } while (workerThread.IsAlive);

            Logger.log.Info("Total frames: " + frame + " Expected frames: " + (ExpectedFrames(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) - 1));

            launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.Close();

#if DEBUG
            string line;
            while ((line = launchingFFMPEG.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Logger.log.Debug(line);
            }
#endif
            launchingFFMPEG.Close();
            alertBox.Show();
        }

        void RequestD3DScreenShot()
        {
            captureProcess.CaptureInterface.BeginGetScreenshot(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), Callback, resize, (ImageFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(ImageFormat), "Bitmap"));
        }

        private void AttachProcess(string exe)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(exe));
            foreach (Process currProcess in processes)
            {
                // Simply attach to the first one found.

                // If the process doesn't have a mainwindowhandle yet, skip it (we need to be able to get the hwnd to set foreground etc)
                if (currProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Skip if the process is already hooked (and we want to hook multiple applications)
                if (HookManager.IsHooked(currProcess.Id))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Direct3DVersion direct3DVersion = Direct3DVersion.AutoDetect;

                CaptureConfig cc = new CaptureConfig()
                {
                    Direct3DVersion = direct3DVersion,
                    ShowOverlay = false
                };

                processId = currProcess.Id;
                process = currProcess;

                var captureInterface = new CaptureInterface();
                captureInterface.RemoteMessage += new MessageReceivedEvent(CaptureInterface_RemoteMessage);
                captureProcess = new CaptureProcess(process, cc, captureInterface);

                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);

            if (captureProcess == null)
            {
                ShowUser.Exception("No executable found matching: '" + exe + "'");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The callback for when the screenshot has been taken
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientPID"></param>
        /// <param name="status"></param>
        /// <param name="screenshotResponse"></param>
        void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            using (Screenshot screenshot = captureProcess.CaptureInterface.EndGetScreenshot(result))
            if (screenshot != null && screenshot.Data != null && arg != null)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    image.Dispose();
                }

                image = screenshot.ToBitmap();
                // image.Save("D3DImageTest.bmp");
                image.Save(launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                launchingFFMPEG.StandardInput.Flush();
                frame++;
            }

            if (frame < 5)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RequestD3DScreenShot));
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.log.Info("Done getting shots from D3D.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display messages from the target process
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        private void CaptureInterface_RemoteMessage(MessageReceivedEventArgs message)
        {
            Logger.log.Info(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I search the internet for the error all I get is the [FFMPEG source code](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/bmp_8c-source.html), which has not proven to be illuminating.  I have been able to save the image directly to disk, which makes me feel like it is not an issue with disposing the data.  I have also tried only grabbing one frame, but that produces the same error, which suggests to me it is not a threading issue.

Here is the full sample of stderr:

```
2016-06-02 18:29:38,046 === ffmpeg version N-79143-g8ff0f6a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers

2016-06-02 18:29:38,047 ===   built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)

2016-06-02 18:29:38,048 ===   configuration: --enable-gpl
--enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib

2016-06-02 18:29:38,062 ===   libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100

2016-06-02 18:29:38,063 ===   libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100

2016-06-02 18:29:38,064 ===   libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101

2016-06-02 18:29:38,064 ===   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101

2016-06-02 18:29:38,065 ===   libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102

2016-06-02 18:29:38,066 ===   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100

2016-06-02 18:29:38,067 ===   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101

2016-06-02 18:29:38,068 ===   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

2016-06-02 18:29:38,068 === [bmp @ 000002cd7e5cc280] not enough data (13070 < 8294454), trying to decode anyway

2016-06-02 18:29:38,069 === [bmp @ 000002cd7e5cc280] not enough data (13016 < 8294400)

2016-06-02 18:29:38,069 === Input #0, image2pipe, from 'pipe:.bmp':

2016-06-02 18:29:38,262 ===   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A

2016-06-02 18:29:38,262 ===     Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1920x1080, 8 tbr, 8 tbn, 8 tbc

2016-06-02 18:29:38,263 === [libx264 @ 000002cd7e5d59a0] VBV bufsize set but maxrate unspecified, ignored

2016-06-02 18:29:38,264 === [libx264 @ 000002cd7e5d59a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2

2016-06-02 18:29:38,265 === [libx264 @ 000002cd7e5d59a0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 1.1

2016-06-02 18:29:38,266 === [libx264 @ 000002cd7e5d59a0] 264 - core 148 r2665 a01e339 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=8 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0

2016-06-02 18:29:38,463 === Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\fores\AppData\Roaming\Affectiva\n_Artifacts_20160602_182857\GameplayVidOut.mp4':

2016-06-02 18:29:38,464 ===   Metadata:

2016-06-02 18:29:38,465 ===     encoder         : Lavf57.29.101

2016-06-02 18:29:38,469 ===     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x180, q=-1--1, 8 fps, 16384 tbn, 8 tbc

2016-06-02 18:29:38,470 ===     Metadata:

2016-06-02 18:29:38,472 ===       encoder         : Lavc57.30.100 libx264

2016-06-02 18:29:38,474 ===     Side data:

2016-06-02 18:29:38,475 ===       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 30000000 vbv_delay: -1

2016-06-02 18:29:38,476 === Stream mapping:

2016-06-02 18:29:38,477 ===   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))

2016-06-02 18:29:38,480 === [bmp @ 000002cd7e5cc9a0] not enough data (13070 < 8294454), trying to decode anyway

2016-06-02 18:29:38,662 === [bmp @ 000002cd7e5cc9a0] not enough data (13016 < 8294400)

2016-06-02 18:29:38,662 === Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

2016-06-02 18:29:38,663 === frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    

2016-06-02 18:29:38,663 === video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

2016-06-02 18:29:38,664 === Conversion failed!
```

In memory, the current image is 320 pixels wide and 180 pixels long.  The pixel format is Format32bppRgb.  The horizontal and vertical resolutions seem odd, they are both 96.01199.  When filed to disk here is ffprobe output for the file:

```
ffprobe version N-79143-g8ff0f6a Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'C:\Users\fores\git\game-playtest-tool\GamePlayTest\bin\x64\Debug\D3DFromCapture.bmp':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Here is a PNG version of an example screenshot from the current code (playing Portal 2):
[image: Portal 2 Screenshot]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  My current workaround is to save the files to the HDD and compile the video after gameplay, but it's a far less performant option.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the input frame size, and does it have an alpha chanel?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I just added that, "In memory, the current image is 320 pixels wide and 180 pixels long.  The pixel format is Format32bppRgb.  The horizontal and vertical resolutions seem odd, they are both 96.01199."  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Can you add the ffprobe readout for the frames?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I have just added ffprobe details for an image example.  The MP4 is always created as 0 bytes, which I should probably have mentioned before.  I have updated the question to mention that the resulting MP4 is 0 bytes.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you convert the images to PNG when saving to disk?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, yes that one was a PNG file internally.  Here is what a bitmap from the program looks like with ffprobe:
Input #0, bmp_pipe, from 'C:\Users\fores\git\game-playtest-tool\GamePlayTest\bin\x64\Debug\D3DImageTest_BIG.bmp':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
PS C:\Users\fores>